# Relationships between N independent samples and a single sample

Tags: sampling

Imagine I have a population of $N=1$ million balls in a bag. I want to draw $M = 10$ independent samples, each having $S = 1\%$ of the total population. Let each ball be marked with a unique identifier.

**Question 1.** If I merge all the samples, which is the expected $\%$ of unique balls? I reckon this is lower than $10\%$ (since the intersection of all independent samples is not empty).

---

Now imagine I want to take $M$ independent samples, each representing $1\%$ of the total population, but I only have access to a subset of it (say, $20\%$).

**Question 2.** What is the statistical impact of drawing $M$ independent samples from an already sampled population? I reckon that any statistical anomaly present in the $20\%$ sample will be propagated to the independent samples, and the error will tend to be inversely proportional to that initial sample size, but how can one calculate its impact?